# Blackberry - Where is phonegap (www) folder stored on Device?

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I am developing for Blackberry usign phonegap and I need to copy all my app files to a writable location (I assume the app file location is red only).

Setting up the plugin to do this is easy enough using Java, however the problem I am having is finding the location of these files specific to my app so that I can copy and move them.

From previous reseaerch it seems that Class.getResourceAsStream would work e.g.

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/index.html");
```

However do not userstand how this can be specific to my app.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlackBerry application file is packaged as *.cod file. It is kinda modified java *.jar file with hierarchical structure (folders, packages inside of the archive).

When you run `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/index.html");` you get index.html file from the root package of your *.cod file. If there's a file attached upon compilation process, then you will get it, otherwise the operation fails.

As you want to use a writable media, then consider FileConnections API of the RIM SDK.

cod files are stored to a special location (not the filesystem). But you will need to deal with the filesystem if you want to write files to the device memory or memory card.

Comment: I need to basically look through and get the whole directory and then move it to a writable location public static void copyDirectory
{ File srcDir = new File("/"); File trgDir = new File("file://store/home/user/ToyotaLexusTaxApp/"); }

Comment: Will File("/"); that retreive my whole directory? Thanks

Comment: File("/") won't give you the entire folder contents. You need to know  all resource names embedded to your cod file to retrieve them. There is no way to list resources embedded into cod file.

Comment: And addional important point, try to avoid use of internal device memory filesystem. It is better to store files on the memory card. Internal device memory filesystem shares the space with the internal application storage, and in case there is no free memory for the internal filesystem the device goes mad and does strange things. I.e random reboot etc.

Comment: I will push the files to the memory card instead of device memory. However, is there any other way that I can get all these files without having to specify each file name, such as a for loop or something (I have over 100 HTML pages that I need to copy)

Comment: The reason for this is I am using phonegap and will be making updates to the HTML which will be being pulled in from a web service. When this happens they weill simply overwrite the current page, hence updating my app (this is why i need these files to access a writable drive). Thanks

Comment: As all my files are within a www folder, could I specify that as the file to copy from e.g. srcDir = new File("/www"); Thanks for the help been looking for days!

Comment: To access resources within your cod file there is only way: getResourceAsStream. You cannot access embedded resources via File class. If you have many embedded resources into your cod file you want to access then make a String array with their names and loop through it to get every resource.

Comment: Sorry to be bothering you but could you point me towards a decent tutorial to create a loop to create a string array of my files. Is this specific for blackberry or can i look into a generic java implementation. Sorry I new to Blackberry development and java for that matter!

Comment: I meant to make array manually in your code. When you are making your application you know the files which are embedded. So declare a predefined string array with names of files you have added to the project. For instance if you have file1.html, file2.html and file3.html added then declare an array like that: String[] resourceFileNames = {"file1.html", "file2.html", "file3.html"};

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8937/discussion-between-rafael-osipov-and-weebo123)

Comment: ah ok I got you and i can still use this for all folder paths as well e.g {"folder1/file1.html", "folder1/folder2/file2.html"} Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use paths for embedded resources and load them in a loop using a previously declared array in your code.

Comment: Will give this all a go and see how I get on, Thanks for the help and I will accept the answer once I have it all up and running.

Comment: I have setup the string in the format above, however cannot seem to work out how to seperate each string and then loop through them, can i use the traditional for(int i=0; i < string.lenght; i++); but not sure what I should be iterating through, the 'string.lenght'section

Comment: was so close to that,  will try implementing it into my app